# How to call Angular Directive inside Vue Js Component

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

`<chat-system options="chatOpts"></chat-system>`

which is defined as **Directive** in **Angular Js (1.Ox)** 
and we are using globally for other systems
Now we want to Integrate the same directive for **`Vuejs Component`**.

Could you help me?